# list favorites?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, bookmarks

I see it tells me very recent changes to any of them and how many. Today, this week, last month e.t.c.

But I don't  want to see changes and I don't want to see just as far as last month. 
Or rather.. I don't mind but i'm not looking for that.

I just want a list of my favorites. From the  perspective of archiving useful info. Not for monitoring.  A list of the threads that I favorited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there on your [profile page](https://superuser.com/users/42672)

[image: Profile favs]

Comment: I see it lists that now.. So now i'm wondering. Where is the option to get it to list what I was seeing before? i.e. how many favourites had changed in a certain period. (then at least i'd have a good idea how to return to the view I have now if it goes again)

Comment: I see now. I was clicking on the Envelope and seeing the favorites option there. It has a favorites option there but on that it just lists recent activity related to it.  I should've clicked on my username.

Comment: @barlop Clicking on the envelop indicates which of your favourites were recently updated. Clicking on your user name -> favourites shows all your favourites. Hope that helps :)